# How do I call a python script.exe on click of a button?

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I have a test.exe written in Python and I want to call it from this location C:\Folder. I know calling .py is possible like the code below:

Code:

```
import sys
import os
from tkinter import *

window=Tk()

window.title("Running Python Script")
window.geometry('550x200')

def run():
os.system('opencv_video.py')

btn = Button(window, text="Click Me", bg="black", fg="white",command=run)
btn.grid(column=0, row=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Is there a similar code that calls the test.exe that I have? Any suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thank you very much

Comment: Did you try `os.system("C:/Folder/test.exe")`?

Comment: @acw1668, thanks for suggesting. I have not thought about it :) trying it now.

Comment: @acw, it worked :) i thought this code is only for .py but also for .exe. Thanks :P